# Multi Taxonomy URL rewrite not wokring

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite WP URL and here is the URL:

http://example.com/?job_listing_region=california&job_listing_category=wordpress

I want to change it as http://example.com/california/wordpress

I tried this:

```
add_rewrite_rule('([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','job_listing_region=$matches[1]&job_listing_category=$matches[2]','top');
```

But its not working. Sorry I am not good at regex it might be a small one but I am not able to find a solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the above answer, they helped me to get an solution finally.

So while passing url strings to wordpress we need to register the variables in functions.php and then instead of using php get we need to use wordpress var queries to get the urls.

As suggested by @athms above, I changed url structure.

Now "wordpress" is a wordpress page in which the query variables are captured.

```
 So my URL is http://example.com/wordpress/?job_listing_region=california
```

In functions.php I registered these variables:

```
function custom_query_vars_filter($vars) {
  $vars[] = 'job_listing_region';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_query_vars_filter' );

function custom_rewrite_tag1() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%job_listing_region%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag1', 10, 0);
```

Rewrite Rule in functions.php:

```
function custom_rewrite_rule3() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^wordpress/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=35349&state=$matches[1]','top');
  }

  add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule3', 10, 0);
```

Here page id is the id of page I created i.e "wordpress"

And in the page template for "wordpress" I captured the region using:

```
$region = get_query_var('job_listing_region');
```

Now you can pass this variable to your query.

So now you can start using this pretty URL:

```
http://example.com/wordpress/california
```

The end of URL california is taken as query string and can be used in our template.

Answer (score 0):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/WWwIFt/1)

**Regex**

```
\??\w+=([^&]+)&?
```

**Replacement**

```
$1/
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
http://example.com/?job_listing_region=california&job_listing_category=alcohol-abuse-programs
```

#### Output

```
http://example.com/california/alcohol-abuse-programs/
```

---

### Explanation

**Regex**

- `\??` Match between zero and one of the `?` character literally
- `\w+=` Match any word character one or more times, followed by the `=` character literally (`\w` can be replaced with `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` if preferred/doesn't work in your regex flavour)
- `([^&]+)` Capture into capture group 1 any character except the `&` character literally one or more times
- `&?` Match between zero and one `&` character literally

**Replacement**

- `$1/` Matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group, followed by a `/` literally

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @ctwheels

Comment: As per @athms above I changed URL to http://example.com/US/?job_listing_region=california&job_listing_category=alcohol-abuse-programs

the regex work here
https://regex101.com/r/WWwIFt/2  But throws a 404

add_rewrite_rule('\??\w+=([^&]+)&?','job_listing_region=$matches[1]&job_listing_region=$matches[2]','top');

Answer (score 0):

Using http://example.com/{job_listing_region}/{job_listing_category}/ is too broad - it would affect every single URL on your website, such as /wp-admin.

I'd recommend using  http://example.com/jobs/{job_listing_region}/{job_listing_category}/ as your URL structure, in which case the rewrite rule would be set as follows:

`add_rewrite_rule('^jobs/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=1234&job_listing_region=$matches[1]&job_listing_region=$matches[2]','top');`

`page_id` should be set to the page ID of the page/post you'd like to route this to.

It's important to note that the rewrite might not be available until you view/save the Settings -> Permalinks page in the back end.

Comment: Thanks for detailed info. I do not redirect to any page or post its an archive.

I have made the url as 
[link]http://example.com/US/?job_listing_region=california&job_listing_category=drug-abuse-programs

And rewrite as

`code` add_rewrite_rule('^US/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','US/job_listing_region=$matches[1]&job_listing_region=$matches[2]','top'); 

But its taking me to a 404 page.